# How to create unique list of dyads from lists within purrr?

Tags: r, data-manipulation, purrr

I'm examining elephant family data over the long-term, and I have a series of code that creates a list of family members alive at each time point selected (in the form of a Julian date e.g. 1224). I'm trying to flip that into a list of dyads, that I can run further manipulations on.

famdat2 = a large vectors list, where each element is family at a time point e.g. AA 1224 (AA family at date 1224 (Julian date format)), listing NATALNAME (individual code), and other life history info (birth and death dates etc.). To create my dyad list I have tried;

```
famlists <- famdat2 %>%
        map(pluck("NATALNAME"))

dyadcreate <- function(y) {
        y %>%
        expand_grid(y)
}

dyads <- map(famlists, dyadcreate)

dyads <- map(dyads,
              set_names,
              c("A", "B"))
```

This successfully generates all pairs as listed elements, but with unnecessary duplication. E.g. individual ABR12 appears in both columns, and you get both A-B and B-A pairs (which are symmetrical and therefore equivalent).

I want to either remove duplicates in the dyads list - both A-A and B-A pairs

OR change my approach so that I end up with a list where each element is of the form

```
dyads[["AA 1224]]
A       B        Dyad
ABR12   AGA82    ABR12-AGA82
ABR12   ALI02    ABR12-AGA02
ALI02   AGA82    ALI02-AGA82
```

So far I have tried discard() and and been trying to write wrapper functions. Other posts led me try;

`dyads2 <- dyads %>% map(dyads, dyAd=paste(sort(c("A", "B")), collapse = "_"))`

but this throws an error:

```
Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
ℹ With name: AA 1224.
Caused by error in `pluck_raw()`:
! Index 1 must have length 1, not 2.
```

I've also tried;

```
is_same<- as_mapper(~.x == .x)
dyads <- map_chr(dyads, safely(discard(dyads, is_same)))
```

which throws the following:

```
Error in `discard()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
ℹ With name: AA 1224.
Caused by error:
! `.p()` must return a single `TRUE` or `FALSE`, not a logical matrix.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Since I'm getting repeat indexing errors, I think I'm missing something about how purrr manipulates lists. I've been through tutorials on datacamp and elsewhere, trying to figure this out. But I remain stuck.